# when do we consider the samples in a calorimeter as a solution in calculation?

Tags: thermodynamics

I noticed some problems consider the samples in a calorimeter as a solution thereby calculating the mass of the **combining samples**, whereas in others I found that they separate the samples into different calculations by using the **distinct mass** and specific heat for each.

could you explain why?

Thanks|!